# How AnalyticService handles Multiple sends

Tags: android, performance, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am in the process of integrating GA with my game. At the end of each level, I send a won event, a timing to capture the time of the level, and a custom dimension to capture the user progress. This helps me with a clean API. 
I am not sure how these method calls handled though, does the service sends three different requests to google, or is it smart enough to roll them in one? 
On the other hand, if it is not smart, does it worth trying to minimize the calls, or it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Google Analytics for Android dispatches the analytics events periodically (every 30 minutes).

You can also override the dispatch period as below.

`GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(60);`

check out the documentation for more info

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

Comment: So it means that I don't need to optimise?

Comment: So preserve your clean API and adjust the dispatch time based on the timing of your game level. Is timing of each level fixed or varying?